# Xubuntu 12.04 + Tex Live 2012 no biblatex binary and no biber

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, ubuntu

I am getting really confused now. I installed Tex Live 2012 on my Xubuntu 12.04 with a backport and I installed TexMaker.

I could user PdfLatex right away and it generated everything I needed except my bibliography. I read that Tex Live 2012 comes with biblatex so I just changed the bibtex command in TexMaker from "bibtex" to "biblatex". However, that does not exist. So I did

```
sudo apt-get remove biblatex
sudo apt-get install biblatex
```

The package is installed but I don't find the binary.
Using bibtex the whole thing crashes. Which does not surprise me since I want to userbiber:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Btw does biber come with biblatex? So far I couldn't get any clear explanation what biber and biblatex are to each other.

**EDIT:**
I had to remove texlive completely and install it with the install script form http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html. Apparently the newest version of biber does not work with the older version of biblatex I had.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: biblatex is a latex package (like hyperref), not a binary. biblatex can be used with the binaries bibtex or biber, where using biber is recommended.

Comment: ah, okay. So I need the biber binary which did not come with Tex Live. I will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the `biber` package, too. This is a separate package in Debian/Ubuntu family.

(X)Ubuntu 12.04 uses biblatex version 1.7-1; you can verify this by running:

```
apt-cache show biblatex
```

According to [the biber documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/documentation/biber.pdf/download), the last biber release to support biblatex 1.7 is biber 0.9.9.

You can download the appropriate version of biber 0.9.9—32bit or 64bit—here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/0.9.9/binaries/Linux/

Comment: Or you could build from source (easy enough on Linux)

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu 12.04 does not have a biber package. I was able to build biber with the help of this [article](http://www.texdev.net/2010/01/23/building-biblatex-biber/).
However, my biblatex is too old for the new version of biber. So I will look into that.

Comment: Yeah, the link between biber and biblatex is tight. I see that you have now installed TeX Live from TUG, so you should get always compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no `biber`-package for ubuntu 12.04, you can go ahead and install the one from ubuntu 12.10. It is still available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/biber/biber_0.9.9+release-1_all.deb. After installing it with `dpkg -i` the dependencies can be pulled via `apt-get -f install`.